# Will Lucene produce smaller files sizes if you index short one character Field names?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

Does Lucene produce smaller files sizes if you index short one character Field names?

For instance, will using "d" instead of "description" produce significantly smaller indexing files on disk?

Or does it map to shorter internal IDs anyway? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field names are stored in the segment index. A segment is quite large. So as expected, using shorter field names would not save much on the file size.